# Manipulating array before using ngCSV in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array that I want to turn into a CSV file. Looks like this:

```
filteredRecords [
{
    date: '', 
    time: '', 
    comments: [
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''}
    ],
    arrival: '',
},
{
    date: '', 
    time: '', 
    comments: [
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''}
    ],
    arrival: '',
}
]
```

ngCSV works like a charm for normal arrays, but it can't handle nested arrays.

I want to **turn the nested array in comments into a string**, so I can use ngCSV to export the file, and do the opposite when importing the file.

It should look like this:

```
filteredRecords [
{
    date: '', 
    time: '', 
    comments: '[{"message":"test","commenttime":"16.29"},{"message":"test","commenttime":"16.29"}]',
    arrival: '',
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
$scope.commenttoJson = function(filteredRecords){
        $scope.json = angular.toJson(filteredRecords);
        console.log($scope.json);
}
```

But this turns the whole **filteredRecords** array into a Json object.

How can I manage to manipulate only the comments object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this work for you?

```js
var filteredRecords = [
{
    date: '', 
    time: '', 
    comments: [
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''}
    ],
    arrival: '',
},
{
    date: '', 
    time: '', 
    comments: [
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''},
        {message: '',
        commenttime: ''}
    ],
    arrival: '',
}
];

var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < filteredRecords.length; i++) {
  newArr.push(filteredRecords[i]);
  if (newArr[newArr.length - 1].comments) {
    newArr[newArr.length - 1].comments = JSON.stringify(newArr[newArr.length - 1].comments);
  }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```