# How to format data to use ng-csv

Tags: angularjs, csv

I have a below object as data:

```
{a:1, b: [2, 40]}, 
{a:3, b: [2, 4]},
{a:3, b: [3, 6]}
```

When I use this format with [ngCsv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv) it gives me below format:

[image]

But I need something like below:

[image]

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xykp9yc3/14/)

Comment: `b.join(", ");` would merge your list into a string

Comment: What change I need to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just type:

```
angular.forEach($scope.getArray, (arr)=>{
  arr.b = arr.b.join(", ");
});
```

after you initialise your `$scope.getArray`

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there anything that let me do like `[2, 40]` in the exported CSV?

Comment: not sure what is the question or what you want to do with `[2,40]`, but alternative may be with `b.toString();` - turning a list into string without a separator (just commas)

Comment: I want to show `[2, 40]` in the file instead of just `2, 40`.

Comment: `JSON.stringify( [2,40] )` will convert it to `"[2,40]"`, so you might need : `JSON.stringify( b )`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Aleksey can you do me a favour by letting me know why `ng-csv` export `"["a"]"` to `""a""`? How to get rid of this?

Comment: what function are you using for this to occur?

Comment: I'm not sure but when I send data to ng-csv its happening

Comment: I can't really give you a good answer if I can see how you manipulate your data, but **stringify** should work, here is a similar case: [Manipulating array before using ngCSV in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286724/manipulating-array-before-using-ngcsv-in-angularjs)

Comment: ```console.log(value)  => value ["demon"]
       0: "demon"
       length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

 console.log(JSON.stringify(value)) =>  ["demon"]```

I am passing above but i'm not why export file is showing `[""demon""]` instead `["demon"]`

Comment: you are expected to get `"["demon"]"`, which is how it should look like, since you have an array of strings, if you want to remove double quotes inside of your list, then you can use **replace** with _regex_: `JSON.stringify(value).replace(/["']/g, "");` to get `"[demon]"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158155/discussion-between-deamon-and-aleksey-solovey).